# How do you send commands with arguments already inside them to GNU parallel?

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel

I have a bash array:

```
nodes=(
    "command"
    "command arg"
    ...
    )
```

and I want to run all the commands with all the arguments that are already attached to them using GNU parallel.

I've tried

```
printf '%s\n' "${nodes[@]}" | parallel python
```

and

```
parallel python ::: "${nodes[@]}"
```

The output command is

```
python path_to_file\ arg
```

and the error it gives is "can't open file 'path_to_file arg'"

I think the problem has to do that backslash - I get the same error when I run the command without parallel.

How do I prevent it from putting the backslash in?

Comment: You need to re-split your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
printf '%s\n' "${nodes[@]}" | parallel eval python
```

`eval` is a shell command that evals the string as shell expression. I typically used it to "de-quote" a string.

or:

```
printf '%s\n' "${nodes[@]}" | parallel python {=uq=}
```

Newer versions of GNU Parallel have `uq()` which leaves the value unquoted. Normally GNU Parallel will quote values.

or:

```
printf '%s\n' "${nodes[@]}" | parallel
```

The exception to the rule above is when there is no command. Then the value is unquoted.

Comment: first one works - nice

What would the second and third one do?
And why does this first one work? I don't know if I've ever used `eval`

Answer (score 1):

You need to split you input on spaces into arguments. You can for example (ab-)use word splitting expansion by the shell. `parallel` passed your arguments as they are, so you run `python "command arg"` - with one argument with literal space preserved. Yet I guess you want `python command arg` - pass two arguments and the space acts as a separator.

```
parallel 'python $*' ::: "${nodes[@]}"
```

Using `xargs` that would look like:

```
printf "%s\n" "${nodes[@]}" | xargs -l sh -c 'python $*' --
```